# How to properly use ng-click in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-click

Hi I have been learning angularjs over a week now.
I have a question on ng-model.

my question is I have a field called firstname:.
When I give the name and hit the submit button.
The firstname has to be displayed in another field called Name:

Here is the code I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var emp= angular.module("empdet",[])
emp.controller("empctrl",function($scope){
$scope.form= function(){

    var display= $scope.firstname;

}

});

</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="empdet">
<div ng-controller="empctrl">
 <div>First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname"></div>
<button  type="button" ng-click=form()>SUBMIT</button>
<div>Name:{{display}}</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
$scope.display = $scope.firstname;
```

Comment: @HAraTest glad that it helped.. can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your `var display` is internal. Change it to `$scope.display`.